# How do I specify the scope with Twitter OAuth?

Tags: twitter-oauth

With Twitter OAuth, the user gets the following:

[image: Twitter app permission request]

I only need to post tweets, is it possible to only ask for only that?

Facebook supports a "scope" parameter when requesting authentication, but I don't see anything like that for Twitter:
[Twitter Authorization](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request)

Comment: Hey, did you find the scope? I am developing Apache Oltu+Twitter example, I do need scope as a mandatory to set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think that is possible at the moment. The only permissions available at the app settings page are "Read only", "Read and Write" (which you're using) and "Read, Write and Access direct messages".